# Почему "золотовалютный" пишется слитно?

Tags: орфография

Как так вышло, что слово **золотовалютный** (резерв) стало писаться слитно? Тут ведь напрашивается объяснение как *золотой и валютный*, что подразумевает чрездефисное написание.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, во-первых, это историческое написание, а во-вторых, толкование может быть не столь очевидным. Здесь, возможно, имеется в виду золото как валюта. Золотовалютный запас = золотая валюта + другая валюта. Идеальным с толчки зрения буквы правил было бы написание "золотовалютно-валютный запас", но понятно, что это всерьез никем не рассматривалось. Выбрали, видимо, из двух зол меньшее.

Во вполне обозримом историческом прошлом залотовалютный запас именовался просто "золотым" (хотя включал в себя далеко не только золото), с освоением новых реалий, появлением и осмыслением понятия "резервных валют", сложился такой именно термин.

> Состоят из средств в иностранной валюте, специальных прав
>   заимствования, резервной позиции в МВФ и *монетарного* золота

(вики, курсив мой)

Вот это-то уточнение ("монетарного", что здесь и равнозначно "валютному") и позволяет по-иному осмыслить предположение о "золотом и валютном".

Comment: Монетарное золото не означает, что оно в монетах. Это значит, что оно является государственным активом, а храниться может и в слитках, и в монетах,  и в любой другой форме.

Comment: Я знаю, что такое монетарное золото..Это именно валютное золото,, используемое в качестве финансового актива. Насчет "государственного" - тут надо разбираться... Банк, скажеи, тоже имеет зотой запас, то есть хранит золото в качестве валюты..Так что тут я бы не настаивал на слове "государственный". Но это отдельный разговор, прямо к теме не относится. Суть моего ответа в том, что золото рассматривается **как валюта**. Этим, возможно, объясняется принятое традиционное написание.

Answer (score 1):

Золотовалютные резервы –  запасы иностранной валюты и золота страны.

Золотовалютный резерв  – **это термин, он не соответствует простому сложению двух прилагательных: золотой и валютный.**

Запасы, хранящиеся в Центральном государственном банке, подразделяют на две группы активов. В первую из них включают **золото**, которое может быть в монетах и в слитках, а также **платину, серебро и алмазы**.  Золотовалютные резервы второй группы – это средства в валюте. В России в нее включают евро и американский доллар. [Золотовалютные резервы стран мира. Что это такое - золотовалютный резерв? | fb.ru](http://fb.ru/article/148013/zolotovalyutnyie-rezervyi-stran-mira-chto-eto-takoe---zolotovalyutnyiy-rezerv)

Поэтому слово образуется способом **чистого сложения основ прилагательных (бессуффиксального)** и пишется слитно: золот/о/валютный.